# Recorrer un Array con un Rand PHP

Tags: php

tengo 4 botones los cuales deben tener opciones (opciones unicas, es decir que no se pueden repetir)

Las opciones estan en una bd de mysql, y todo funciona bien excepto que se repiten las opciones

Las demás funciones que tengo es para que la consigna coincida con las respuestas y eso.

```
function rndResponse (){

    GLOBAL $rnd;

    $max = 3; 

    $rnd = rand(0, $max);

    $opciones = array("Correct_Option", "Option_1", "Option_2", "Option_3");

    $response = getResponse($opciones[$rnd]);

    echo $response;

}
```

y luego llamo a esta función desde un html mediante el value del input, pero, repito, hay veces en que las opciones se repiten.Tengo cuatro botones y llamo a la función en el value de cada uno de ellos:

```
<input type="button" value="<?php rndResponse(); ?>"> 
input type="button" value="<?php rndResponse(); ?>"> 
<input type="button" value="<?php rndResponse(); ?>"> 
<input type="button" value="<?php rndResponse(); ?>">
```

Hay alguna forma de que esto no suceda?

Comment: Hay varias opciones dependiendo dónde quieras implementarlo: **1** No cargar duplicados en la base de datos; **2** Obtener sólo valores únicos con el quey; o **3** Eliminar los duplicados de `$opciones` con **[`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-unique.php)**

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! El problema no es que haya respuestas en la bd duplicadas, sino que imprimo la respuesta duplicadas veces segun el rand. Un Saludo!

Comment: El problema con el código es que no hay una forma de saber cuál respuesta ya fue impresa, y asumo que llamas la función `rndResponse()` varias veces (por medio de un foreach o similar).

Comment: Ok. Eliminá del array la opción devuelta, y `--$max`

Comment: Tengo cuatro botones y llamo a la funcion en el value de cada uno de ellos


<input type="button" value="<?php rndResponse(); ?>">
input  type="button" value="<?php rndResponse(); ?>"> 
<input type="button" value="<?php rndResponse(); ?>"> 
<input  type="button" value="<?php rndResponse(); ?>"> >

Answer (score 2):

El problema radica en que no estás determinando de alguna forma cual respuesta ya fue impresa o no y llamar la función cada vez desde el input no nos ayuda mucho.

---

Una opción según el diseño de de tu aplicación sería determinar el orden de las respuestas antes de mostrar los botones:

```
<?php

    $opciones = ["Correct_Option", "Option_1", "Option_2", "Option_3"];

    // para mezclar el array
    shuffle($opciones);

    foreach ($opciones as $opcion) {
?>

        <input type="button" value="<?php getResponse($opcion); ?>">

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Muchaas Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

En vez de ejecutar el código PHP para cada uno de los inputs, sería recomendable imprimirlos en una sola ejecución del código:

```
<?php
    // Popular el array
    $opciones = array("Correct_Option", "Option_1", "Option_2", "Option_3");

    // mezclar el array aleatoriamente
    shuffle($opciones);

    // imprimir todos los valores como inputs
    foreach ($opciones as &$valor) {
        echo '<input type="button" value="' . getResponse($valor) . '">';
    }
?>
```

De esta forma se imprimen todos los valores de `$opciones`. Si en cambio se requiere imprimir hasta un máximo `$max`, se puede cambiar el `foreach` por

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $max; $i++) {
    echo '<input type="button" value="' . getResponse($opciones[$i]) . '">';
}
```

Comment: Muchaas Gracias!!!